# How to line up a discussion about a bullet point?

Tags: support, formatting

I have the following three bullet points in text like this:

> - BP 1
> - BP 2
>
> Yada yada
>
> - BP 3

---

How do I get "Yada yada" to line up the text "BP 2". In other words I want the same indentation as the text "BP 2", but without the bullet point marker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put two spaces at the end of BP 2, and don't leave a blank line after that:

```
* BP 1
* BP 2[space][space]
Yada yada

* BP 3
```

> - BP 1
> - BP 2
>     Yada yada
> - BP 3

---

If you *must* have a blank line, do the same trick by putting two spaces at the end of a blank line, but now "yada yada" must be properly indented:

```
* BP 1
* BP 2[space][space]
[space][space]
  Yada yada

* BP 3
```

> - BP 1
> - BP 2
>
>   Yada yada
> - BP 3

Answer (score 6):

To keep it neat you can use html `<br>` command.

> `* BP1`
>   `* BP2<br>Yada yada`
>   `* BP3`

yeilds:

> - BP1
> - BP2
>   Yada yada
> - BP3

OR:

> `* BP1`
>   `* BP2<br><br>Yada yada`
>   `* BP3`

yields:

> - BP1
> - BP2
>   Yada yada
> - BP3